# Is it possible to use Xenforo theme in an external app?

Tags: php, xenforo

I've an external app that is using Xenforo 2 session data to determine who is currently logged into my forums. This works fine as I'm able to do a lot of stuff in my app (like creating a thread, making a post etc) and then have it reflected in my forums as well.

But the only thing missing is the theme. I was wondering if that can somehow be used in my external app as well so that when a user redirects from the forums to my app, he doesn't notice the change.

This is for Xenforo v2 btw.